# Spring jdbcTemplate TNS:no appropriate service handler found

Tags: java, spring, connection-pooling, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm getting the following error:

Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@62613365: startup date [Wed Sep 25 11:51:12 BST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is **java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found**

I have 2 beans configured for this:

```
@Bean
public BasicDataSource setDataSource() {
    final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    dataSource.setUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUsername(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(BasicDataSource dataSource) {
    final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
    jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return jdbcTemplate;
}
```

And then I have a repository with the following simple functionality:

```
public Map<String, Object> getTicketsToProcess(Long collectionId,String docId) throws ParseException, DataAccessException {

        String sql = "something";   

        try {
            return jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(sql);
        }catch(DataAccessException dae) {
            dae.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Could you provide your opinion of what's causing this issue?
**This is not always happening!**

Comment: How did you access Jdbctemplate in your repository throw setter or constructor injection?

Comment: did you autowired JdbcTemplate?

Comment: @MangduYogii yes!

Comment: @MangduYogii Through field-based dependency injection.